# ANSI colour text not displayed in pytest-html report

Tags: python, html, pytest, ansi-colors

In pytest html report, the ANSI colour text is not displayed correctly. But in console, I can see the output with out any issue.Please see my `conftest.py` and let me know if I have to make any changes to be displayed correctly.

```
from datetime import datetime
from py.xml import html
import pytest
import json
import globals
from Process.RunProcess import RunProcess
from os import path
import sys
from ansi2html import Ansi2HTMLConverter
from ansi2html.converter import main, \
    ANSI_VISIBILITY_ON, ANSI_VISIBILITY_OFF, \
    ANSI_BLINK_SLOW, ANSI_BLINK_FAST, ANSI_BLINK_OFF, \
    ANSI_NEGATIVE_ON, ANSI_NEGATIVE_OFF, \
    ANSI_INTENSITY_INCREASED, ANSI_INTENSITY_REDUCED, ANSI_INTENSITY_NORMAL
from ansi2html.util import read_to_unicode


@pytest.mark.optionalhook
def pytest_html_results_table_header(cells):
    # cells.insert(2, html.th('Status_code'))
    cells.insert(1, html.th('Time', class_='sortable time', col='time'))
    cells.pop()


@pytest.mark.optionalhook
def pytest_html_results_table_row(report, cells):
    # cells.insert(2, html.td(report.status_code))
    cells.insert(1, html.td(datetime.utcnow(), class_='col-time'))
    cells.pop()


@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    # Ansi2HTMLConverter(linkify=True).convert(outcome.get_result())
    report = outcome.get_result()
    # report.status_code = str(item.function)
```

please see the difference of Console out put and html report from the attached images.[[image: console[1]]

[image: HtmlReport]

Comment: Can someone please answer my question as I am looking forward to getting the answer desperately.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it works right after I installed the required dependency `ansi2html` as described in https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-html#ansi-codes
(without using the `Ansi2HTMLConverter`). However, I don't implement the `pytest_runtest_makereport` hook.